# electromechanical torque

Tags: power

I work for a Utility that has several hydro generation facilities.  We have a consulting firm performing a full load rejection transient analysis on the penstocks at one of the facilities. One of the data points they have requested is upon a full load rejection how quickly does the electrical torque drop to zero.

Can the electrical torque be calculated, what is formula and parameters needed?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4124250/

Comment: What is "electrical torque"?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know nor found any information on the magnetic torq under full load rejection. However once I experienced a full load rejection on the then still operational Mnt Coffee Hydro in Liberia. If I remember well it took about 5 to 10 seconds before the generator (50 MW) became quiet running again when it tripped from the grid. The whole section was vibrating like there was an earthquake. Then the govener stept in and started to close the wicket gates.

In the link below you can find some discussion concerning your request. I believe there can be some usefull information enclosed

http://control.com/thread/1267218529